# Generic Class to create a Generic Collection using IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, oop, generics

This is a **Two (2) Part Question about Generics**

I've got to create several similar classes to model similarly designed database tables.

All tables contain an `ID int` and a `Text nvarchar(50)` field. One or two may contain a few other fields.

I rarely use [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/generics/info), but I see examples of it on here quite frequently. This is my largest attempt to create a generic class that is used in another generic class.

My basic construct is as follows, and I will point out with a comment what does not work and the error message Visual Studio 2010 is displaying:

```
public class IdText {

  public IdText(int id, string text) {
    ID = id;
    Text = text;
  }

  public int ID { get; private set; }

  public string Text { get; private set; }

}

public class TCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IdText {

  private List<T> list;

  public TCollection() {
    list = new List<T>();
  }

  public void Add(int id, string text) {
    foreach (var item in list) {
      if (item.ID == id) {
        return;
      }
    }
    list.Add(new T(id, text)); // STOP HERE
    // Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T'
    // because it does not have the new() constraint
  }

  public T this[int index] {
    get {
      if ((-1 < 0) && (index < list.Count)) {
        return list[index];
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  public T Pull(int id) {
    foreach (var item in list) {
      if (item.ID == id) {
        return item;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public T Pull(string status) {
    foreach (var item in list) {
      if (item.Text == status) {
        return item;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  #region IEnumerable<T> Members

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach (var item in list) yield return item;
  }

  #endregion

  #region IEnumerable Members

  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return list.GetEnumerator();
  }

  #endregion

}
```

Visual Studio's *IntelliSence* wants me to add `list.Add(T item)`, but I need to create this first.

I have attempted to re-write the offending line `list.Add(new T(id, text));` as `list.Add(new IdText(id, text));`, but then I am reprimanded with the message *"cannot convert from `IdText` to `T`"*.

How exactly do I get around this?

**Next:** When I go in to actually create a version of this `IdText` class later, I am not sure how exactly I can use this new class in the `TCollection` class I have designed for it.

For example, given this derived class:

```
public class ManufacturedPart : IdText {

  public ManufacturedPart(int id, string partNum, string description)
    : base(int id, string partNum) {
    Description = description;
  }

  public string Description { get; private set; }

}
```

...would I need to also derive a special version of `TCollection` to accompany it, like so?

```
public class ManufacturedParts<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : ManufacturedPart {

  // OK, now I'm lost! Surely this can't be right!

}
```

Comment: Just a note that `TCollection` is probably a bad name for your collection class, since in C#, the `T` prefix is usually used for generic type arguments, not real types.  (This is unlike, say, Delphi.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You could use the `new()` constraint, make your properties public and add a parameterless constructor:

```
public class IdText
{
    public IdText()
    {
    }

    public IdText(int id, string text)
    {
        ID = id;
        Text = text;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

}

public class TCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IdText, new()
{

    private List<T> list;

    public TCollection()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(int id, string text)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item.ID == id)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        list.Add(new T { ID = id, Text = text }); 
    }
}
```

2) You have multiple options:

If you want your collection to store any `IdText` (`ManufacturedPart` or anything else that derived from `IdText`):

```
TCollection<IdText> ss = new TCollection<IdText>();
```

The above, for now, can only store `IdText` as you instantiate objects in the `Add(int, string)` method, but if you provide a `Add(T object)` method, it could store any `IdText` instance.

If you want your collection to only contains `ManufacturedParts`:

```
public class ManufacturedParts<T> : TCollection<T> where T : ManufacturedPart, new()
{
     // Provide here some specific implementation related to ManufacturedParts
     // if you want. For example, a TotalPrice property if ManufacturedPart
     // has a Price property.
}

TCollection<ManufacturedPart> ss2 = new ManufacturedParts<ManufacturedPart>();
```

or even simpler, if your collection doesn't provide any additional method depending on the type of the stored objects:

```
TCollection<ManufacturedPart> ss2 = new TCollection<ManufacturedPart>();
```

Even simpler, if your goal is to only store objects, a custom collection isn't needed:

```
List<IdText> ss2 = new List<IdText>();  // Uses the built-in generic List<T> type
```

Answer (score 1):

About the first question: c# doesn't support constructors with parameters as a generic constrain. Something you can do is replace it with

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),new object[]{id,text});
```

By the other hand... you don't actually know how the constructors of the derived class will look like, so you can't ensure they will have that constructor.

About the second question, you can do this:

```
var collection = new TCollection<ManufacturedPart>();
```

in the same way List works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will fail when `T` is a subclass of `IdText` that doesn't  have a matching constructor.

Comment: Yep, that's what I said :) but, if he needs it that way, it can be defined by convention

Answer (score 1):

If your collection class will be responsible for **instantiating** elements of its collected type, then you probably don't want to be using either the `new()` constraint or `Activator.CreateInstance()` -- as [Jon Skeet has blogged](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/08/22/optimization-and-generics-part-1-the-new-constraint.aspx), both of these exhibit poor performance.

It sounds like what you actually want is a **provider** delegate, like so:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IdText {
    private readonly List<T> list;
    private readonly Func<int, string, T> provider;

    public MyCollection(Func<int, string, T> provider) {
        this.list = new List<T>();
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public void Add(int id, string text) {
        list.Add(provider(id, text));
    }
}
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
var collection = new MyCollection((id, text) => new ManufacturedPart(id, text));
```

You can think of this as passing the specific constructor you want to use as an argument into the class, which it then uses to construct instances as needed.

And you don't need to create a separate subclass for `MyCollection<ManufacturedPart>` -- just use the generic class directly.

Comment: I am liking this more and more. How does that Jon Skeet character know so much?

Comment: Can't say I really understand how this whole `Func<x, y>` thing works, but I am using it in my code and it is performing flawlessly! Outstanding.

Comment: @jp2code: Yeah, Jon Skeet is [something of a legend around here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).  As far as the various `Func` delegates, they're just predefined generic delegate types defined in the standard library.  Here's a simple [lambda expression tutorial](http://linqtutorial.net/LambdaExpression.html) that might make it clearer to you; you might also want to start with the MSDN documentation on [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx).